# How to install pyATS on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install *pyats* in my system and I have installed python3 version but it gives me an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package pyats


sudo apt install pyats
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [install](https://pubhub.devnetcloud.com/media/pyats/docs/getting_started/index.html#installation) it using pip:

```
pip install pyats
```